# How to get rid of Cursor and use UPDATE with SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I believe that the cursor used in this code is the reason for some major performance issues, however I am new to TSQL.

Following script runs on SQL SERVER 2008. I am trying to redo it so I use JOIN statements instead, however I have not been able to do so successfully.

```
DECLARE AIRAMSDET CURSOR FOR
SELECT BILL, RECIEPT, NAME
FROM Client_Table
WHERE IsProcessed = 1 
AND TYPE IN ('Sub','First_Time','Old') AND LEN(BILL) > 1

OPEN AIRAMSDET
FETCH AIRAMSDET into @VARBILL, @VARRECIEPT, @VARNAME
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE archieve
    SET entry = left(@VARBILL + '- '+ @VARNAME)
    WHERE archiveID = @VARBILL
END
```

Comment: Since there is no `fetch` within the loop it will process the same row for a _long_ time.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like following

```
UPDATE ARCHIEVE
    SET ENTRY = CT.BILL + '-' + CT.NAME
FROM CLIENT_TABLE CT
WHERE 
        ARCHIEVE.ARCHIVEID = CT.BILL
    AND CT.ISPROCESSED = 1 
    AND CT.TYPE IN ('Sub','First_Time','Old') AND LEN(BILL) > 1
```

I have not included LEFT() as its use in your query wasn't very clear. Left takes an integer_expression as its second parameter while you are passing @@VARNAME which most likely is a VARCHAR. Please add that as you deem fit.